# Whatever happened to \newfontinstance?

Tags: fontspec, xetex, texlive

I just installed a pretest version of TeXLive 2010 and tried compiling some files as a test.  None of my XeLaTeX files compile because apparently the command `\newfontinstance` (which was defined in `fontspec`, if I remember correctly) no longer exists.

Reading the documentation (`texdoc fonstspec`) I see that this is indeed the case and that there are now other commands such as `\fontspec`, `\newfontfamily`, ...

### Question

What is the minimal change I have to do to my XeLaTeX documents to get them to compile?  Is is simply a question of changing `\newfontinstance` to `\newfontfamily`?

### Added

It seems that making the above change works (insofar as the document compiles and looks alright), but I'd like confirmation that I'm doing the right thing.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't really see what you need, given that you already solved your problem and confirmed this works...

Comment: What I needed was Will's assurance that the two commands were functionally interchangeable.  I grant you that I could have tried to download an old version of the fontspec source and compared, but the whole point of sites like this is that whereas this would take a considerable amount of time on my part, it's immediately answerable by the author of the software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a somewhat inadvertent change in fontspec v2, but as far I know you're the first person to notice :-) You are correct that \newfontfamily is the replacement to use -- it is exactly the same command with a more sensible/accurate name.

You can write

```
\let\newfontinstance=\newfontfamily
```

in fontspec.cfg if you would like to fix this for all of your legacy documents. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Will, many thanks for your answer.  The change in `fontspec.cfg` is probably the way to go, given the number of documents I have.