# A file I compiled under TeXLive 2009 cannot be compiled under TeXLive 2010

Tags: fonts, texlive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whatever happened to \newfontinstance?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732/whatever-happened-to-newfontinstance)

I compiled the following code with TexLive 2009 before. However, I get the following error message now.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg
undefined contorl sequence
<recently red> \newfontinstance

l.14 \newfontinstance {\sifont}[Script=Sinhla]{LKLUG}
?
```

I have the `sinhala.sty` in my `~/library/texmf/tex/latex` folder.

The following is the LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sinhala}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}

\title{සිංහල අකුරු}
\author{සැලෙන මනස විසිනි}
\date{}                                           
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flushleft}
මේ වාර්තාව පිලියෙල කලේ XeLaTeX භාවිතා කරමිනි. මෙහි අකුරු පැබැඳුම සඳහා TeXShop භාවිතා කල අතර,  අකුරු ලබා ගත්තේ Mac OS X 10.6 හී Character Viewer මගිනි. මේ සිංහල Unicode අකුරු LKLUG මිනිස් සමූහය විසින් නිර්මානය කරන ලද්දකි.
\vspace{10pt}

මෙවැනි වාර්තාවක් පිලියෙල කිරීම සඳහා XeLaTeX භාවිතා කිරීමේදී අනුරැද්ධ රත්නවීර විසින් රචිත ``සිංහල මල්ල" (sinhala package) යොදා ගත යුතුය.
\vspace{10pt}

වාසනාවකට මෙන් මේ සඳහා Keyboard එකද භාවිතා කල හැකිය.  ඒ සඳහා කොලඹ විශ්ව විද්‍යාලයේ \href{http://www.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/feconverter/t1.html}{සිංග්ලිශ්} භවිතා කර ඔබේ වාර්තාවේ අලවන්න.
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Whatever happened to \newfontinstance?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732/5764). You need to put `\let\newfontinstance=\newfontfamily` after loading `fontspec`.

Comment: I fixed the problem.  I found the answer from this site.  Thanks.  I changed the line \newfontinstance{\sifont}[Script=Sinhala]{LKLUG} in the style sheet sinhala.sty to \newfontfamily{\sifont}[Script=Sinhala]{LKLUG} and saved it as sinhala1.sty in my ~/library/texmf/tex/latex folder.  You have to do this because there is a sinhala.sty in TexLive2010 somewhere and it is the default.  I contacted the author of sinhala.sty but he has not responded yet.  Overall, I am very happy with your site.

Comment: Just wanted to mention to you that TeXlive2011 has been released. (Which would not have solved your problem, but you might want to think about updating nevertheless.)