# Tanwin does not appear in the output

Tags: arabic, arabxetex

Normally the output should be appear like

[image]

But actually it appears like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabxetex, arabtex}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontinstance\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontinstance\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{farsi}
ایضاً
\end{farsi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence  \newfontinstance`

Comment: I can compile the file with `xelatex`without error.

Comment: I'm used to use `\newfonfamily` not `\newfontinstance`

Comment: To  enable vocalization you need to insert `fullvoc` option `\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}`

Comment: Thanks Samir Bou, unfortunately I only use the vowels occasionally and  if I use `fullvoc`,  many unwanted vowels appear in my document.

Comment: `\newfontinstance` is replaced with `\newfontfamily`  in new versions of `fontspec` http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732/54817

Comment: Rather then `fullvoc` you can use `voc`

Comment: Many thanks using `\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}` seems to solve my problem. If you like please consider to convert your comments to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default vocalization of Arabic letters is deactivated with `arabxetex`, you can activate it with `\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}`, if you want a full vocalized text you can get it with `\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}`

Note that `\newfontinstance` is replaced with `\newfontfamily` after `fontspec v2`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontinstance\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontinstance\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{farsi}
ایضاً
\end{farsi}

\end{document}
```